# Ruby nomethoderror for multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I am working on Ruby program where I am creating wordsearch puzzle. I have 10x10 double array "`arr`" and I use a method to find a random starting position (example: `arr[5][9]`), then I choose a direction but I am having problem where it goes out of bounds.

Example: one of the words that needs to be placed into puzzle is "dog". I get starting position `arr[5][9]` and iterate through "dog", placing it in the array horizontally one letter at a time. So `arr[5][9]` is "d", `arr[5][10]` is "o", but when it try to place "g" my program crashes and I get error saying "`no method [] for nil: nil class (no method error)`". I know that this is because it is going out of bounds, but how can I stop it from doing that? thank you

edit: If the word can not fit, I want my program to choose a new starting position until the word can fit. I also want to prevent it from going out of bounds

Comment: Do you want it to return an error saying the word can't be placed because it is too long? Do you want the g of dog to be on the left-most index? If you could post some code and what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 10 x 10 array then all indexes should be between 0 and 9.  You need to guarantee that the word will not exceed the bounds of the array in either dimension.

So if you have a word *dog*, for example, then the starting index must be between 0 and 7.

Here is a method you can use for this, with examples of it being called:

```
2.3.0 :001 > def random_x_value(word)
2.3.0 :002?>   rand(10 - word.length)
2.3.0 :003?>   end
 => :random_x_value
2.3.0 :004 > 16.times { print "#{random_x_value('dog')}  "}; puts
4  1  5  1  5  6  3  0  4  5  4  5  2  3  3  5
 => nil
```

[I had previously used `(0..(10-word.length)).to_a.sample` but then realized that I could use `rand(10 - word.length)` which is simpler and clearer.]

Comment: I have edited the answer to use `rand` which is simpler and clearer than the `....to_a.sample` approach I originally used.

Answer (score 0):

```
def random_position(nrows, ncols, word)
  c = ncols - word.size
  rand(nrows * c).divmod(c)
end

20.times { p random_position(10, 10, 'dog') }
[5, 6]
[4, 4]
[9, 4]
[1, 6]
[8, 1]
[8, 6]
[5, 6]
[1, 6]
[1, 1]
[3, 0]
[5, 3]
[1, 5]
[6, 3]
[4, 2]
[1, 5]
[1, 3]
[4, 1]
[7, 2]
[1, 2]
[7, 1]
```